# Clojure: Extracting vectors in vectors

Tags: clojure

I am programming a card game, but i found myself having trouble to extract cards from played tricks.

```
(def a '([[:p1 [10 :h]] [:p2 [9 :s]] [:p3 [10 :s]] [:p4 [11 :s]]]
         [[:p1 [10 :h]] [:p2 [9 :d]] [:p3 [10 :h]] [:p4 [11 :d]]]))


(->>
 (for [[v x y z] a] [(second v) (second x) (second y) (second z)])
 (reduce (fn [c d ] (concat c d) )  )
 )
```

Result:

```
([10 :h] [9 :s] [10 :s] [11 :s] [10 :h] [9 :d] [10 :h] [11 :d])
```

There a always 4 players, but the tricks can be more. Is there an easier way to extract all cards, that were played, than my proposed way? I have the impression my algorithm is a bit too complicated.

Comment: i guess you're looking for something like `(mapcat (partial map second) a)`

Comment: @leetwintski nice, how can learn as good as you?

Comment: or with list comprehension `(for [player a [_ card] player] card)`

Answer (score 2):

Whenever possible, it is a good idea to flatten the data in a first step. It makes things easier to reason about:

```
(->> a
     (apply concat)
     (map second))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just build it up incrementally.  Starting with [my favorite template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template), we type:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(verify
  (let-spy-pretty
    [a  '([[:p1 [10 :h]] [:p2 [9 :s]] [:p3 [10 :s]] [:p4 [11 :s]]]
          [[:p1 [10 :h]] [:p2 [9 :d]] [:p3 [10 :h]] [:p4 [11 :d]]])
     x1 (apply concat a)
     ]
    )
  )
```

Start it running with `lein test-refresh`.

Looking at the value for `a`, we see a 2-element list (2 tricks). Since the problem doesn't care about tricks, we want to concatenate them all. See the [Clojure CheatSheet](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template#documentation) for details on `concat`,
with result

```
--------------------------------------
   Clojure 1.11.1    Java 1.8.0_345
--------------------------------------

Testing tst.demo.core
a =>
[[[:p1 [10 :h]] [:p2 [9 :s]] [:p3 [10 :s]] [:p4 [11 :s]]]
 [[:p1 [10 :h]] [:p2 [9 :d]] [:p3 [10 :h]] [:p4 [11 :d]]]]
x1 =>
[[:p1 [10 :h]]
 [:p2 [9 :s]]
 [:p3 [10 :s]]
 [:p4 [11 :s]]
 [:p1 [10 :h]]
 [:p2 [9 :d]]
 [:p3 [10 :h]]
 [:p4 [11 :d]]]
```

Maybe now add a `for` loop with destructuring.  Code:

```
(verify
  (let-spy-pretty
    [a     '([[:p1 [10 :h]] [:p2 [9 :s]] [:p3 [10 :s]] [:p4 [11 :s]]]
             [[:p1 [10 :h]] [:p2 [9 :d]] [:p3 [10 :h]] [:p4 [11 :d]]])
     x1    (apply concat a)
     cards (vec (for [[player card] x1]
                  card))]
    (is= cards
      [[10 :h] [9 :s] [10 :s] [11 :s] [10 :h] [9 :d] [10 :h] [11 :d]])))
```

which includes both a unit test and the result printed

```
cards =>
[[10 :h] [9 :s] [10 :s] [11 :s] [10 :h] [9 :d] [10 :h] [11 :d]]
```

The version with `map second` has the same result as our destructured `for` expression.

Just replace `let-spy-pretty` with `let` and you are good to go.